# Maven plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have the same problem like on the below link , and solution from there works
but i have a little of hard time in understanding what it cause this and how it affects the project.

[Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration (JBossas 7 EAR archetype)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype)

I start reading about m2e

http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

What is the difference between the 'eclipse build' and maven one ?

Still not clear what is meant by "interesting" and "not-interesting" mojo executions:

https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+build+lifecycle+mapping

So there is the solution but , not the understanding of the problem.

Thanks for helping me understand the problem ...:)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, The way m2e used for resolving/mapping plugins' goal execution into Eclipse build life cycle has been reinvented after version 0.12. Now m2e requires explicit instructions what to do with all Maven plugins bound to "interesting" phases of a project build lifecycle. By either configure the lifecycle mapping in your project's pom, or use specific m2e configurator Eclipse plugin if somebody has kindly created it for the community.

By "interesting" they mean phases which normally occur during writing and debuging of code inside the IDE, mostly excluding packaging and deployment steps.

Also note (from this [blog post](http://grumpyapache.blogspot.com.ar/2011/08/mess-that-is-m2e-connectors.html)):

> M2E allows you to run Maven manually. You can invoke a goal like "mvn install" from within Eclipse just as you would do it from the command line. That works (and always worked) just fine. Unfortunately, Maven is also invoked automagically from M2E whenever Eclipse builds the project, for example after a clean. In such cases M2E acts as an "Eclipse Builder". It is these latter invocations that people have always had problems with and that the connectors should handle better.