# Plugin maven-antrun-plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration with m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, maven-antrun-plugin

I know [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype) but I'm still struggling on solving this issue. When I load projects into eclipse I get the following exception:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (execution: generate-webapp-name, phase: compile)
```

My maven project consists of many modules (>200) and it causes problems on all of them.

I tried ignoring the `run` and `compile` goals in my `pom.xml` (in the parent module):

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore/>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @user944849 - There's no expected behaviour. I just want to import the projects to eclipse and don't see the exception I mentioned. The pom.xml code I provided was taken from a similiar question (with other plugin) that explained the problem and why it's happening. I followed the different questions but the problem remains.

Comment: Try selecting all of the projects, then right-click and choose `Maven --> Update Projects...` and see if that helps.

Comment: @user944849 - First thing I did, a lot before posting a question ;)

Comment: Always good to eliminate the obvious first.  Try this next.  Open a command line window, cd to the top project directory, then run `mvn clean install` (outside of Eclipse). Then, go back to Eclipse, select all of the projects, and refresh them.

Comment: Also did that :/ Also I ran `mvn eclipse:clean` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, nothing :/

Comment: Suggest editing your question to list all of the things you have tried.  Also, are you using m2e or m2eclipse?  They are not the same, and using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` could actually be harmful.

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify that the goal that you set for your maven-antrun-plugin (in my case, `run`) should be **executed**. For anyone that get to this page, add this code before the `plugins` tag:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Source [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/87)

For what is worth, I'm using a very simple ant code. The plugin code I'm using is this one below. I used the `deploy` phase, but you can use another one if you want

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>antrun.package</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <mkdir dir="${destinationBasePath}/WEB-INF/classes"/> 
                        <copy todir="${destinationBasePath}\WEB-INF\classes">
                            <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/classes" includes="**" />
                        </copy>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't accept it because it was 3 years ago. I already switched 2 workplaces since and I don't have how to reproduce it (nor do I remember this issue). Thanks for your answer. Hope others will find it useful :)

Comment: No problem. The intention was really to help the new visitors. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this solution; hope others can find it quicker.