# M2Eclipse Plugin Execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have installed m2eclipse in Eclipse Indigo and the nightmare began. I used command line to run "mvn clean install" and then "mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse". After that, inside eclipse I refreshed my application. After rebuilt in eclipse, the problem tab is filled up "plugin executed not covered by liftcycle configuration..." errors.

I tried to unintall m2eclipse without luck. so I added something in below. I am sure they are correct as I followed "quick fix --> Permantently mark goal in pom.xml as ignored in Eclipse build ". I rebuild in command line and refreshed eclipse, these errors are still there. What can I do to get rid of those errors from the problem tab? It looks so messy. Thanks!

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse 
            m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to m2e :) You can check the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype) for possible solutions.

Long story short, you'll need to modify your pom.xml to make m2e happy. Or altertatevly, you can use [Apache Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) or switch to Idea IDE. I never worked with the apache plugin, but IDEA one works good.