# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration pom.xml error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, javafx

I am starting my journey with Maven and I have some problems with it (I guess basic stuff). I have to merge JavaFX and Spring, that is why I chose eclipse (Kepler) and I downloaded STS plugin which include Maven. I tried to make simple Maven project but I got those errors:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)  pom.xml /sample line 6  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources) pom.xml /sample line 6  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile) pom.xml /sample line 6  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)  pom.xml /sample line 6  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Here is my auto-generated pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>new</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>sample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>sample</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

If I create Maven project in Spring IDE there is no such a problem (but I can't install fx plugins there).

Can someone explain to me (idiot-like) how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try to right click on your project, go to Maven -> Click on Update Project !

Comment: I have tried, but nothing happends

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of [How to solve “Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration” for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) and [Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration (JBossas 7 EAR archetype)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype).  Try the workarounds described there and if they fix your issue, this question can be closed as a duplicate.