# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have below configuration in my pom.xml file

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jslint</goal>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
 .............
</plugin>
```

I see below error in eclipse kepler

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
 net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.3.0:compress (execution: default, phase: 
 compile)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
 net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.3.0:jslint (execution: default, phase: 
 compile)
```

I am not sure whats causing this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration (JBossas 7 EAR archetype)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142533/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-jbossas-7-ear-archetype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add these jslint and compress in the life cycle mapping of the maven. In default it is not covered by the maven life cycle. In the pom you may have quick links to add the life cycle mapping otherwise you have to add it manually in your pom.xml file.

```
     <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
         <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                          <pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                 <executions>
                                   <execution>
                                    <phase>compile</phase>
                                      <goals>
                                      <goal>jslint</goal>
                                       <goal>compress</goal>
                                     </goals>
                                    </execution>
                                  </executions>
                                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            < /configuration>
                         </plugin>
                       </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
```

This code will help maven to include the plugin to life cycle mapping. hope it helps!!